# How to React to an Introduction Email

Tags: etiquette, email

So, someone (A) introduced me to someone else (B) via email, so that I can ask B questions and get advice. The email is directed at B, and I am copied. Should I wait for B to email me, or should I email B first? If the latter, should I reply to the original email and copy A, or should I just open another thread with B?

Also, I don't know if it is important or not, but the email ends like this:

> Thanks for connecting with him, he is copied on this email.

Needless to say, "him" means me.

Comment: You are thinking too much... just email B however you want to ask your questions. Since you are asking B for help there should be no expectation that B should take the initiative and responds to you first.

Comment: I wonder why would someone be the first downvote of a question without providing feedback in the comment section :?

Comment: @Drecate That's what I was going to do. But I thought I might come out as assuming B agrees to connect to me, which might sound offensive to B. I am aware that most probably these sorts of thoughts are overthinking, but based on my experience sometimes they are not, so that's why I bothered asking. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If B does not want to help then they won't reply...

Comment: There are no rules here. This is human communication, which is not subject to strict protocols. This is the good thing about academia, as the formalities are not considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it worrying to see so many questions like this. They make academia seem like a terrifying place. It really isn't. Standard rules of engagement  apply (pun intended).

> So, someone (A) introduced me to someone else (B) via email, so that I can ask B questions and get advice. The email is directed at B, and I am copied. Should I wait for B to email me, or should I email B first?

Unless cultural rules say otherwise, **you should email B first**. Beyond saving B time (in emailing you unnecessarily), you can ask for what you want.

> If the latter, should I reply to the original email and copy A, or should I just open another thread with B?

**Reply to the original email, do not copy A, perhaps blind copy A**, maybe mentioning you've done so to avoid bombarding them with further mail, e.g., *Thanks for the kind introduction A (bcc to avoid further inclusion).*

(Don't start a new thread with B. That thread wouldn't include the introduction and B may forget who you are.)

Comment: -1 because nothing to do with academia. Exchanging emails and messages is a normal activity everywhere.

Comment: @Younes Presumably you mean "[the question has] nothing to do with academia," that's a -1 for the OP, not me, imo. If I have misunderstood, then please do elaborate.

Comment: @user2768 I did not comment on your answer... My comment was for the OP...

Comment: @user2768 I don't agree that the OP's question or similars can "make academia seem like a terrifying place". The question and the answer are true under any working circumstances (e.g. company). I don't find it helpful to defend academia from something of which it is not accused.

Comment: @Younes So, your -1 is because of my opening sentence. I'll defend it: The OP asked their question because they are concerned about sending an email. Yet, this is a regular activity. So, we can infer that something concerns the OP about a regular activity. That must surely be environmental. I fully acknowledge that _terrifying_ overstates (my perception of) the environmental concern. Nonetheless, there's clearly a problem with academia if regular activities are causing concern. I find that worrying

Comment: @user2768 "That must surely be environmental". I don't agree. It is more 'personal' in my opinion. Overthinking can be in any situation and not necessarily related to the working environment. The OP does not know (B) and made some assumptions which are not shared with us but they led to ask such a question. Where is the relation to academia here? As long as this answer can be answered by anyone (even those who didn't join the university at all) then it is not about academia. Rather, it is about social behaviour at workplace (any workplace)

Comment: @Younes I guess it isn't my opening sentence you disagree with. You're still emphasising the disconnection with academia. Perhaps you'd favour: They make _the workplace_ seem like a terrifying place. That might be true, but I haven't seen questions about the workplace, only about academia (on this website). Anyhow, I'm still unsure whether I'm understanding your objection.

Comment: @user2768 It is rather an opinion and I don't think we will make things clearer by more comments. My intention is to improve the quality of the answers and "maybe because of my background" I want that the latent meaning is also true. So, please ignore my comments if you don't find them helpful.

Comment: @Younes It isn't that I don't find them helpful. I don't think I have yet understood them

Comment: @user2768 "I don't think I have yet understood them" -> Ignore them ;)

Comment: Thank you. I think regardless of whether this is academia problem or not, there should be a place (not necessarily here of course, but I cannot find any other platform) that accepted "social protocols" can be discussed. They may seem trivial to the majority of people, I agree, but there are some people like me with social anxiety or little social interaction experience that feel desperate in such situations :D

Comment: @Feri Personally, I have no problem with such questions. They come up a lot. And I encourage academics to post here. Why would an academic post in a generic forum, when a specialist forum exists? That said, such questions may be voted as off-topic. As an alternative, there's https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Two sorts of people could have asked this question: (1) I know the standard social convention but am not sure it applies in academia. (2) I don't know any convention about this, academic or otherwise. In case (1), the question is on topic, and so is the answer, including its first paragraph. In case (2) the objection from @Younes applies to both the question and the answer. When I read the question, I considered (1) to be the more likely situation, but I see that the question should have been clearer.

Comment: @Feri has clarified that his question is not specific to academia. I am not against that it is asked here. However, the opening of user2768 makes it specific to academia and this is not true. The opening gives the impression that except most working places, academia and maybe few other working places seem socially terrific but they are not. I hope my idea is clarified.